# Highlight two different subsets of data points in boxplot with ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, highlight

I am new to R and got some help to set up boxplots with ggplot. What I wanted was boxplots for data in different categories with a specific set of data points highlighted for each boxplot. The highlights are for specific substances (the whole data set covers many different substances).

This is how it looked like:

```
    #FFnew
FFnew <- read_excel("C:/R/FFnew.xlsx")

FFnew$highlight <- c(TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE,TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE,TRUE, rep(FALSE, nrow(FFnew) - 15L))

FFnew <- melt(FFnew) # convert df to long format


#skapa grundfigur
p <- ggplot(subset(FFnew, !highlight), aes(x=Name, y=value)) +
  geom_boxplot() + scale_y_log10(breaks = trans_breaks("log10", function(x) 10^x),
                                 labels = trans_format("log10", math_format(10^.x)))+
  geom_point( # add the highlight points
    data=subset(FFnew, highlight),
    aes(x=Name, y=value),
    color="red", size=5
  )

#editera figur
p +labs(x = "Receiving compartment", y ="Freshwater emission fate factor [days]") + theme(axis.text=element_text(size=15),
                                                                                          axis.title=element_text(size=15))
```

Now I have basically the same data sets but I want to highlight two different subsets, preferably with two different kinds of dots. I cannot figure out how to do this and would very much appreciate some tips.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can use  in ggplot(data, aes(x=Name, y=value, fill = value_to_highlight))
and for type of point you can use  geom_point( # add the highlight points
    data=subset(FFnew, highlight),
    aes(x=Name, y=value),
    color="red", size=5, shape = if(condition, yes, no)
  )

Comment: Or if you prefer to specify the shape of dots only, use ````+ geom_point(data, aes(x = Name, y = value, shape = value_to_highlight))````.

Comment: The most ggplot-y way would be to use the `hightlight` variable as aesthetic, e.g. fill, color or shape.  You can then use `scale_...` functions (e.g. `scale_shape_manual`) in order to assign "looks" to the different values of the variable

Comment: Also - welcome to SO. We hope that you will have many future questions and answers. Please have a look how to improve your questions, this will help future us to help you:)  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask